# Javascript - Webpack Error only on Safari v16.4.1

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, webpack, safari

I've built a web app using Inertia / Vue JS and Laravel. When using the app in Chrome / IE / Firefox, the app works fine without issue.

I have since a recent update had users complaining about a blank white screen. I've got new relic setup on the site and have tracked it down to this error :

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't[e].call')

I've got access to Browserstack and have tried it on multiple iOS devices and am yet to come across this white screen. It is there and showing for only safari, but I really am unsure as to why.

I've linked the sourcemap up in NewRelic and it's pointing to this line of code, built by Webpack

```
return Promise.all(ids.slice(1).map(__webpack_require__.e)).then(() => 
{
 return __webpack_require__(id);
});
```

Versions are as follows

- Laravel Mix v4.0.7
- NPM Version 8
- Vue Version 3
- Laravel 5.8

*Erroring Browser Safari V16.4.1*

Has anyone come across this issue before and had a solution? I wish I could replicate it, but I can't seem to do it across any of my devices.

**Update** this appears to be when a user sets the website onto their homescreen. So I suspect this is a cache thing. Will look to clear cache, or offer a clear of cache to the user, see if that solves it!

Thanks

Tried a newer version of webpack and yarn modules, no luck. I suspect it may be the browser permission for push notifications